# Variable Assignment issue

Tags: java

I am creating a project that allows user to do what you usually can with a bank(create, delete accounts, withdraw, deposit, print transactions).

My problem is printing transaction. I am able to print something but the wrong values are coming up. For example, when you create a bank account, you will need to input a opening balance which was (5.00). When I print transaction,  nothing comes up. So I deposit money into the same account (10.00), when I print, the (5.00) from before comes up and the (10.00) appears in the transactionDate. However, when I view the account balance, it all adds up to what it show be.

Can someone help me troubleshoot and fix the problem?

```
package mainsample;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        BankProcess bankProcess = new BankProcess();
        TransactionProcess transactionProcess = new TransactionProcess();


    Bank bank = new Bank();
    BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount();

    int input;
    int selection;

    while(true) {
      System.out.println(""); 
      System.out.println("######## MENU ########");
      System.out.println("[1] Create an account");
      System.out.println("[2] Print all existing accounts");
      System.out.println("[3] Delete an account");
      System.out.println("[4] Deposit");
      System.out.println("[5] Withdraw");
      System.out.println("[6] Print transactions");
      System.out.println("[0] Exit");      
      System.out.println("######################");
      System.out.println("Please choose one of the following: ");
      selection = scan.nextInt();

      switch (selection) {

        case 0:
          System.out.println("Exit Successful");
          System.exit(0);
            break;

        case 1:
          System.out.println("'[1] Create an account' has been selected.");
          System.out.print("Account Id: ");
          int accountId = scan.nextInt();
          scan.nextLine();

          System.out.print("Holder Name: ");
          String holderName = scan.nextLine();

          System.out.print("Holder Address: ");
          String holderAddress = scan.nextLine();

          System.out.print("Opening Balance: ");
          double openingBalance = scan.nextDouble();

          System.out.print("Open Date: ");

          String openDate = scan.next();

          bankAccount = new BankAccount(accountId, holderName, openingBalance, holderAddress, openDate);
          bank.setAccounts(bankProcess.openNewAccount(bank.getAccounts(), bankAccount));

          System.out.println("Successfully Added.");
          break;      

        case 2:
          System.out.println("'[2] Display all existing accounts' has been selected");
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
            bank.getAccounts().forEach((i,b)->System.out.println(b));
          System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("[3] Delete an account has been selected");
            System.out.println("Enter the account ID: ");
            int accountNo = scan.nextInt();
            bankAccount = bank.getAccount(accountNo); // get bankAccount from account id
            bank.removeAccounts(bankProcess.removeAccount(bank.getAccounts(), bankAccount));
            System.out.println("Account has been deleted.");
      break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("[4] Deposit has been selected");
            System.out.println("Enter account ID: ");
            int accountNumber =  scan.nextInt(); 

            System.out.println("Enter deposit amount: ");
            double depositAmount = scan.nextDouble();           

            transactionProcess.deposit(bankAccount, depositAmount);


            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("[5] Withdraw has been selected");
            System.out.println("Enter account ID: ");
            int accountNu =  scan.nextInt(); 

            System.out.println("Enter withdraw amount: ");
            double withdrawAmount = scan.nextDouble();           

            transactionProcess.withdraw (bankAccount, withdrawAmount);           

            break;           


        case 6:
            System.out.println("[6] Print Transaction has been selected");
            System.out.println("Enter account ID: ");
            int accountN = scan.nextInt();
            bankAccount = bank.getAccount(accountN);
            for (Transaction transaction: bankAccount.getTransactions()) {
            // print transaction information ...
            System.out.println(transaction.toString());

}



            break;






        default:
          System.out.println("Your choice was not valid!");

      }

    }
  }
}
```

```
package mainsample;

/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class Transaction {


  private String transactionType;
  private double transactionAmount;
  private int transactionDate;


  public Transaction() {}

  public Transaction( String transactionType, double transactionAmount, int transactionDate) {

    this.transactionType = transactionType;
    this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
    this.transactionDate = transactionDate;

  }

  public int getTransactionDate() {
      return transactionDate;
  }

  public void setTransactionDate (int transactionDate) {
      this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
  }


  public String getTransactionType() {
    return transactionType;
  }

  public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) {
    this.transactionType = transactionType;
  }

  public double getTransactionAmount() {
    return transactionAmount;
  }

  public void setTransactionAmount(double transactionAmount) {
    this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
  }

  //Override the toString() method of String ? 
  public String toString() {
    return "\nTransaction Amount : "+ this.transactionAmount +
           "\nTransaction Type : " + this.transactionType +
           "\nTransaction Date:  " + this.transactionDate;

  }

}
```

```
package mainsample;
/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class TransactionProcess {

    public void deposit(BankAccount bankAccount, double depositAmount) {
    //Get the CurrentBalance
    double currentBalance = bankAccount.getCurrentBalance();

    //First Argument : set the Id of transaction
    //Second Argument : set the Type of Transaction
    //Third Argument : set the TransactionAmount 
    //Fourth Argument : set the Balance Before the transaction (for record purposes)
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction("Deposit", currentBalance, (int) depositAmount);

    if (depositAmount <= 0) {
      System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");
    } else {
      //Set the updated or transacted balance of bankAccount.
      bankAccount.setCurrentBalance(currentBalance + depositAmount);
      //then set the MoneyAfterTransaction

      bankAccount.addTransaction(transaction);    // adds a transaction to the bank account
      System.out.println(depositAmount + " has been deposited.");
    }

  }

  // Explanation same as above
  public void withdraw(BankAccount bankAccount, double withdrawAmount) {
    double currentBalance = bankAccount.getCurrentBalance();
    Transaction transaction = new Transaction("Withdraw", currentBalance, (int) withdrawAmount);

    if (withdrawAmount <= 0) {
      System.out.println("Amount to be withdrawn should be positive");
    } else {
      if (currentBalance < withdrawAmount) {
        System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
      } else {
        bankAccount.setCurrentBalance(currentBalance - withdrawAmount);        
        bankAccount.addTransaction(transaction);    // adds a transaction to the bank account
        System.out.println(withdrawAmount + " has been withdrawed,");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mainsample;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class BankAccount {
    private int accountId;
    private String holderName;
    private String holderAddress;
    private String openDate;
    private double currentBalance;

    private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

    //Provide Blank Constructor
    public BankAccount(){}

    //Constructor with an arguments.
    public BankAccount(int accountNum, String holderNam,double currentBalance, String holderAdd,String openDate) {
            this.accountId = accountNum;
            this.holderName = holderNam;
            this.holderAddress = holderAdd;
            this.openDate = openDate;
            this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    }

    // Always Provide Setter and Getters
    public int getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }
    public void setAccountId(int accountId) {
        
         this.accountId = accountId;                  
    }
    public String getHolderName() {
        return holderName;
    }
    public void setHolderName(String holderName) {
        this.holderName = holderName;
    }
    public String getHolderAddress() {
        return holderAddress;
    }
    public void setHolderAddress(String holderAddress) {
        this.holderAddress = holderAddress;
    }
    public String getOpenDate() {
        return openDate;
    }
    public void setOpenDate(String openDate) {
        this.openDate = openDate;
    }
    
    public double getCurrentBalance() {
        return currentBalance;
    }
    public void setCurrentBalance(double currentBalance) {
        this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    }

    public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void setTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }
    
    public void addTransaction(Transaction transaction){
      if(transactions.size() >= 6){  // test if the list has 6 or more transactions saved 
      transactions.remove(0);     // if so, then remove the first (it's the oldest)
     }
     transactions.add(transaction); // the new transaction is always added, no matter how many other transactions there are already in the list
     }

    public String toString(){
        return "\nAccount number: " + accountId + 
                "\nHolder's name: " + holderName + 
                "\nHolder's address: " + holderAddress + 
                "\nOpen Date: " + openDate + 
                "\nCurrent balance: " + currentBalance;
    }

   
}
```

```js
package mainsample;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class Bank {
    
    private TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> bankAccounts = new TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount>();

 
    
    public TreeMap<Integer, BankAccount> getAccounts() {
        return bankAccounts;
    }
    public void setAccounts(TreeMap<Integer, BankAccount> accounts) {
        this.bankAccounts = accounts;
    }
    
     public BankAccount getAccount(Integer accountNumber){
     return bankAccounts.get(accountNumber);
     }

    
    public void removeAccounts(TreeMap<Integer, BankAccount> accounts) {
        this.bankAccounts = accounts;
    }

   
}
```

```js
package mainsample;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class BankProcess {
    // return the  Updated list of BankAccounts
    public TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> openNewAccount(TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> bankAccounts,BankAccount bankAccount) {
        //Get the List of existing bank Accounts then add the new BankAccount to it.
        bankAccounts.put(bankAccount.getAccountId(), bankAccount);        
        return bankAccounts;
    }
    
    public TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> removeAccount(TreeMap<Integer,BankAccount> bankAccounts,BankAccount bankAccount) {
      bankAccounts.remove(bankAccount.getAccountId(), bankAccount);
      return bankAccounts;  
        
    }
    

    

}
```

Comment: Where is your bankaccount class?

Comment: Is it possible that you are not getting the actual with ´bankAccount = bank.getAccount(accountNo);´ from case 4 and 5?

Comment: @andresoviedo what do you mean?

Comment: @InsideFootball you are asking user to enter account number, but you are not getting that account. You are working with the previous selected account.

Comment: @andresoviedo how can I fix it?

Comment: Bank and bankprocess class where is it?

Comment: @InsideFootball You are actually doing well in case 3 or 6.  Just realize what are the differences ;)

Comment: @almasshaikh all my classes are up now

Answer (score 0):

First you made a mistake in Transaction constrctor

```
public Transaction( String transactionType, double transactionAmount, int transactionDate) {

        this.transactionType = transactionType;
        this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
        this.transactionDate = transactionDate;

    }
```

But you are assigning like this

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction("Deposit", currentBalance, (int) depositAmount);
```

your argument order is totally wrong here. why are you assigning deposit amount instead of date. it should be like

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction("Deposit", (int) depositAmount,date );
```

Also when you create a new Account you haven't add that amount into Transaction. You are creating the new account using this code

```
bankAccount = new BankAccount(accountId, holderName, openingBalance, holderAddress, openDate);
bank.setAccounts(bankProcess.openNewAccount(bank.getAccounts(), bankAccount));
```

But you haven't add this initial amount into transaction. it should included inside the constructor of bankAccount

```
Transaction transaction = new Transaction("Deposit", 0, (int) depositAmount);

if (depositAmount <= 0) {
  System.out.println("Amount to be deposited should be positive");
} else {
  //Set the updated or transacted balance of bankAccount.
  bankAccount.setCurrentBalance(currentBalance + depositAmount);
  //then set the MoneyAfterTransaction

  bankAccount.addTransaction(transaction);    // adds a transaction to the bank account
  System.out.println(depositAmount + " has been deposited.");
}
```

Now i'm getting correct output. when you create the account you asked date. when you deposit you haven't asked date. So you can't assign a transaction date for deposit or withdrawal

```
Transaction Amount : 5.0 Transaction Type : Deposit Transaction Date:  4

Transaction Amount : 10.0 Transaction Type : Deposit Transaction Date: 10
```

Comment: why did you change currentBalance to 0?

Comment: when you create a new account current balance should be 0. also you made some mistakes in Transaction Process constrctor.check it

Answer (score -1):

You're not calling:

bankAccount = bank.getAccount(accountN);

to point your bank account in point 4 (deposit) and 5 (withdraw).

FIX:

```
   case 4:
        System.out.println("[4] Deposit has been selected");
        System.out.println("Enter account ID: ");
        int accountNumber =  scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("Enter deposit amount: ");
        double depositAmount = scan.nextDouble();           
  --->  bankAccount = bank.getAccount(accountN);
        transactionProcess.deposit(bankAccount, depositAmount);


        break;

    case 5:
        System.out.println("[5] Withdraw has been selected");
        System.out.println("Enter account ID: ");
        int accountNu =  scan.nextInt(); 

        System.out.println("Enter withdraw amount: ");
        double withdrawAmount = scan.nextDouble();           
  --->  bankAccount = bank.getAccount(accountN);
        transactionProcess.withdraw (bankAccount, withdrawAmount);           

        break;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. Point 4 and 5 works. I can test it by looking at the current balance. It's the transactions that ain't work properly (printing)

Comment: @andresoviedo, i'm testing his application and typing the answer, don't see your comment

Comment: @Inside Football no, I'will explain better: in case 4 and 5 you don't reference the account of your choice but, if you have choose some account in other case, you reference that, or, if you didn't chose any option you will reference the BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount(); instantiated in line 16.

Comment: @razcor can you refer to what section is incorrect.

Comment: @razcor you could mark your answer as 'community wiki'. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Comment: @Inside Football in Main class, you've a Switch, case 4 and case 5, I posted the solution in my answer, FIX section, just c&p and test.

Comment: @andresoviedo i'm just reading the link of this best practice, thx to point it to me.